# upload a photo from my facebook albums to my site using in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, image-uploading

I have get all the albums from facebook to my site.
And all the photos
Actually i want that when user want to change is profile picture i would give him option to select from his facebook pictures.
How could i upload or select the picture as i have got all the picture but don't know how to upload as 
i have got the facebook photos as

```
<?php foreach($photos['data'] as $photo) {?>

<img src="<?php echo $photo['source'] ?>"height="100" width="100" />
<?php } ?>
```

in this tab i got selected albums photos

this will only upload from the system.
any help

Comment: I recommend looking at the Facebook PHP SDK for this - it's fairly well documented and it should make it reasonably straightforward to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have upload the picture to my site from a given link by

```
$url = $_POST['photo_link'];
        /* Extract the filename */
        $filename = time() . '.jpg';
        /* Save file wherever you want */
        file_put_contents('upload/' . $filename, file_get_contents($url));
```

And it was bingo